# How can I purchase Roblox game pass products remotely. (Ex. python)

Tags: post, cookies, roblox

I am experimenting with ideas for a Roblox game, and I was wondering if it was possible to remotely purchase game pass products from players' inventory. I have tried to use many Roblox interactors but couldn't figure out how to make it work. If anyone could provide information on how I could do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

I had tried to use pyblox, but I could not get it to work, many errors occurred, and I have little to no knowledge on how to get API requests to work. I have also tried using http requests from the Roblox game itself, but I could not get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to access the user's authentication token from outside of Roblox, which I doubt most of your app's users trust you with.